# how to return external js function?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, payment-gateway

I am integrating custom payment. The payment provider gives a script from their side.
need to call a function from their script with the generated token. By calling that function, it will redirect to payment site.

How can I return the js function?
can Someone guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Is it in form of external JS file for which you have URL provided by the payment provider?

Comment: no it is not form. so the Process is need to post shipping, total etc details. i did it by using ZendClientFactory as response i get token. i need to pass that token in payment provider js function @dudzio